# Eclipse IDE build target question

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am creating an android project from an existing source, The android project is a third party project that runs on every other machine but mine. The behavior, at the New Android Project creation wizard, it says Build Target BUT doesn't give any targets to build. How can I get the android sdks in the build target menu so i can open and run this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you specified the Android "SDK Location" in the Android preferences (Window -> Preferences -> Android)?